# get list of all h1 entry of org-mode buffer or file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Given file (`file.org`) like this:

```
* h1 t1
* h1 t2
* h1 t3
```

How can I read the file and get a list such as this?

`("h1 t1" "h1 t2" "h1 t3")`

Comment: Better than what? Also "better" is in the eye of the beholder. You should ask: "Is there a way...?" - then if there are multiple answers, you can select the one that you prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a mapping function to walk the file, applying a function to each headline. There are two different ways of doing that.

---

One method uses the mapping function `org-map-entries` and the function `org-entry-get` from the "Property API". You can find documentation on these by doing `C-h f org-map-entries` and `C-h f org-entry-get` or from the manual: see the "Hacking" section and the [Using the Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html#Using-the-Property-API) and [Using the Mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html) subsections.

Here's the code:

```el
  (defun my/headline ()
     (org-entry-get nil "ITEM"))

  (org-map-entries #'my/headline t 'file)
```

`ITEM` is a [Special Property](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) whose value is the text of the headline.

---

Another method is to parse the buffer and get a parse tree and then operate on the parse tree. The parsing function is `org-element-parse-buffer` and the mapping function that walks the parse tree is `org-element-map`. These functions are not documented in the manual, but their doc strings are available through the usual `C-h f` mechanism; there is also developer documentation [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html). The ideas are similar to those of the first method, but the details differ: we get the headline text from the parsed object that is passed by the mapping function, so this headline function takes an argument, the parsed object of the headline. The mapping function itself walks the parse tree, applying the function to each headline:

```el
  (defun my-parsed/headline (o)
    (plist-get (cadr o) :raw-value))

  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline #'my-parsed/headline)
```

This method is slightly more complicated but it is more general and, after having parsed the tree once, you can cache the parse tree and operate on it repeatedly: that is going to be faster than the first method if you amortize the cost of producing the parse tree among many different operations. But for one-off usage like here, the first method is simpler and probably a little faster: the parser is relatively slow.